# Hot to append form input to appear as comment section user ID?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am working on a comment section for a project.

I have the following php code:

```
<?php
     echo "<form method='POST' action='".setComments($conn)."'>
        <input type='hidden' name='uID' value='Anonymous'>
        <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'>
        <textarea name='message'></textarea><br>
        <button class='submit-button' type='submit' name='commentSubmit'>Comment</button>
    </form>";

    getComments($conn);

?>
```

The setComments() and getComments() are here:

```
function setComments($conn) {
    if(isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])){
        $uID = $_POST['uID'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO commentSection (uID, date, message) 
        VALUES ('$uID', '$date', '$message')";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    }
}

function getComments($conn){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM commentSection";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<div class='comment-box'><p>";
            echo $row['uID']."<br>";
            echo $row['date']."<br>";
            echo nl2br($row['message']);
        echo "</p>

            <form class='delete-form' method='POST' action='deleteComments.php'>
                <input type='hidden' name='commentID' value='".$row['commentID']."'>
                <button type='submit' name='commentDelete'>Delete</button>
            </form>

            <form class='edit-form' method='POST' action='editComment.php'>
                <input type='hidden' name='commentID' value='".$row['commentID']."'>
                <input type='hidden' name='uID' value='".$row['uID']."'>
                <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".$row['date']."'>
                <input type='hidden' name='message' value='".$row['message']."'>
                <button>Edit</button>
            </form>
        </div>";
    }
}
```

Now, I have created the following form element using bootstrap:

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I make it so that this form input, or the first name, value shows up here:

```
<input type='hidden' name='uID' value='Anonymous'>
```

instead of the default 'Anonymous' value?